# Don't understand why Potential Function Works

Tags: calculus, linear-algebra, matrices, game-theory, algorithmic-game-theory

Consider a puzzle as illustrated below:
$$
A=\left[\begin{array}{cccc}
0 & 1 & 0 & 0\\
0 & 2 & 0 & 0\\
2 & 0 & 0 & 0\\
0 & 0 & 0 &3
\end{array}\right]
$$
where a $0$ indicates that the box in initially empty.

Model the puzzle as a game with
the following specifications:
Boxes with a $0$ are modeled as players in game, i.e., there are $12$ players in the above
game.

Actions of each player $i \in N$ is $\mathcal{A}_i=\{1,2,3,4\}$.

Utility of each player $i \in N$ is $$U_i(a_i,a_{-i})=-(\text{# reps in row})-(\text{# reps in col})-(\text{# reps in block}),$$ where reps means repetitions.

Note that a game is an exact potential game if there is a function $\phi: \mathcal{A}\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ such that $\forall a_{-i} \in \mathcal{A_{-i}}, \forall {a^{'}}_{i}, {a^{''}}_{i}$
$$\phi({a^{'}}_{i}),a_{-i})-\phi({a^{''}}_{i}),a_{-i})=\mu_{i}({a^{'}}_{i}),a_{-i})-\mu_{i}({a^{''}}_{i}),a_{-i})$$.

(Note $A_{-i}$ simply denotes the actions of all players except $i$ thus $(a_i,a_{-i})$ encompasses actions of all players)

Solution says function: **$\phi(a)=\frac{1}{2} \sum_{i \in N} U_{i}(a)$ is a potential function for the game.**

I, however, cannot convince myself that this potential function is correct. I have tried many examples as below:
Suppose consider puzzle:
A=$$
A=\left[\begin{array}{cccc}
0 & 0 & 0 & 0\\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0\\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0\\
0 & 0 & 0 &0
\end{array}\right]
$$
Thus, there are 16 players in the above game.
Note I am calling Player 1's corresponding matrix entry $(1,1)$, Player 2: (1,2), Player 3: (1,3), Player 4:(1,4), Player 5:(2,1), Player 6: (2,2), Player 7: (2,3), Player 8: (2,4), Player 9:(3,1), Player 10: (3,2), Player 11: (3,3), Player 12: (3,4), Player 13: (4,1), Player 14: (4,2), Player 15: (4,3), Player 16: (4,4).

Suppose $1=a_{1}=a_{2}=a_{3}=a_{4}=......a_{15}=a_{16}$.
All players choose number the number 1. 
Then we have that payoff for Player 1:
$$U_1(1,1,1,1,......1,1)=-3-3-3=-9$$ as the number 1 is repeated 3 times in Player 1's row, 3 times in Player 1's column, and 3 times in Player 1's block.
Suppose instead that Player 1 chooses number 2, but all other players choose number 1:$$U_1(2,1,1,1,......1,1)=-2-2-2=-6$$ as the number 1 is repeated 2 times in Player 1's row, 2 times in Player 1's column, and 2 times in Player 1's block.

Thus, we see the difference in payoffs is -3.

However, we now calculate the potential function:
Clearly $$\forall i,  U_i(1,1,1,1,......1,1)=-3-3-3=-9$$
Thus
$\phi(1,1,1......1)=\frac{1}{2}(16\times-9)=-72$

However, calculating the payoffs for $a'=(2,1,1,1,1...1,1)$ is more complicated:
\begin{align*} 
U_1(2,1,....1)=-2-2-2=-6 \\ 
U_2(2,1,....1)=-2-3-2=-7\\
U_3(2,1,....1)=-2-3-3=-8\\
U_4(2,1,....1)=-2-3-3=-8\\
U_5(2,1,....1)=-3-2-2=-7\\
U_6(2,1,....1)=-3-3-2=-8\\
U_7(2,1,....1)=-3-3-3=-9\\
U_8(2,1,....1)=-3-3-3=-9\\
U_9(2,1,....1)=-3-2-3=-8\\
U_{10}(2,1,....1)=-3-3-3=-9\\
U_{11}(2,1,....1)=-3-3-3=-9\\
U_{12}(2,1,....1)=-3-3-3=-9\\
U_{13}(2,1,....1)=-3-2-3=-8\\
U_{14}(2,1,....1)=-3-3-3=-9\\
U_{15}(2,1,....1)=-3-3-3=-9\\
U_{16}(2,1,....1)=-3-3-3=-9\\
\end{align*}
Thus $\phi(2,1,....1)=\frac{1}{2} \sum_{i \in N} U_{i}(2,1,...1)=\frac{1}{2}(-132)=-66$

Thus, it is not working for me as the difference in the payoffs is $-9-(-6)=-3$ but the difference in the potential functions is: $-72-(-66)=-6$

However, these quantities are supposed to be equal for $\phi$ to be a potential function. **Thus, is $\phi(a)=\frac{1}{2} \sum_{i \in N} U_{i}(a)$ not a potential function for the game, despite it being stated as so or am I making a mistake in my calculations or interpretations of anything? Thank you.**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The formulation in the problem statement is rather unclear, but from the context of the potential it seems that what they mean by “# reps” is the number of times the player’s number is repeated by other players. So if the player switches to $2$, their payoff goes to $0$ because there are no other $2$s in the row, column or block. The idea behind the potential function and the factor $\frac12$ in it is that the sum of all payoffs counts each pair of matching numbers twice, but that only works if we interpret ‘# reps” accordingly.

Comment: Using the definition of reps as number of times the players number is repeated by other players and  the payoff of player 1 as you say goes to $0$. But then the sum of the payoffs would be -126 instead of -132 (increase by 6 from what I have), and $\frac{1}{2}\sum{U_{i}}=-63$ and the difference in the potential functions would thus be $-72-(-63)=-9$ when we want them the difference to be $-3$ so I don't completely follow.  With the way, I have defined repetitions as above do you think potential function $\frac{1}{4}\sum{U_{i}}$ works?

Comment: Oh but then $U_1(2,1,1,1....1$) would be 0 so the difference in payoffs would be -9 and the difference in potentials would be -9 so I see why that works for your interpretation of repetition. But, nevertheless I would like to find a potential function for my interpretation for repetition (that is the number of times numbers are repeated by a player in a particular row, or col etc.) does the potential function $\frac{1}{4} \sum U_{i}$ work in that case?

Comment: @forreal: Yes, it does. Each matching number is counted $12$ times, including $3$ times for the player whose number it is, so the factor for the potential must be $\frac3{12}$. In the other case, each matching number is counted twice per match, including once for the player whose number it is, so the factor for the potential must be $\frac12$.

Comment: My last couple of questions sorry. Just want to be really sure I understand. What do you mean by matching number? Why is each matching number counted 12 times and specifically 3 times for the player whose number it is? Finally then my last question is, so if I have a 9 x 9 game, instead of a 4 x 4 game, then I presume the potential function would be $\frac{1}{9} \sum U_{i}$? This last question is my most important question. Thanks.

Comment: @forreal: By "matching number" I meant a number that occurs more than once in the respective group (row, column or block). By "match" I meant a matching pair of such matching numbers. In your version of the game, a matching number is counted towards the payoff of all players in all groups in which it occurs. It occurs in one row, one column and one block, each of which contains $4$ players. Some of these players are in more than one of these groups, but then the matching number counts as many times towards their payoff, so in total it's included $3\cdot4=12$ times in the sum over all payoffs.

Comment: @forreal: In the payoff of the player whose number this is, it's included $3$ times, once for each group. (That player is the only one who's a member of all three of those groups.)

Comment: @forreal: About the $9\times9$ game: Each number is still in $3$ groups, but these now contain $9$ numbers each, so in your version of the game each matching number is counted $3\cdot9=27$ times in the sum over all payoffs. It's still only counted $3$ times for the player whose number it is, so yes, the ratio is now $\frac3{27}=\frac19$. In the original version of the game, the ratio is still $\frac12$, because each match of a matching number is still counted towards the playoff of two players, one of which is the player whose number it is.

Comment: thanks it makes a lot of sense now. So to formally prove that $\frac{1}{9} \sum U_i$ is indeed the potential function would I use indicator functions to count the number of repetitions in each row, col, or block? I'm not exactly sure how to proceed/ what a proof sketch would look like.

Comment: @forreal: I'm the wrong person to ask about that :-) In my view, a proof is anything that convinces other competent people that something must be the case. There are people on this site who write more formal proofs and might have more to say on what such a proof should entail in this case.

Comment: no problem thanks.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/106134/discussion-between-forreal-and-joriki).